# how to place dynamic href from a tag in JSF?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee

I want to use a tag in my JSF page, but i also want to have dynamic href content. I know there is a h:commandLink in JSF but i don`t want use it for my purposes. I have t:dataTable elemet which iterates via results and shows them on my page. Here is the situation:

```
<t:dataList id="dataTable" value="#{manBean.fullResult}" var="element" first="0" rows="10">
<div class="photos">
<a href="  IN THIS PLACE I WANT DYNAMIC CONTENT "><img src="myimages/IN THIS TOO.../image.jpg"</a>
</div>
...
</t:dataList>
```

I have tried code like this:

```
<a href="myimages/#element[0]/image.jpg"><img src="myimages/#element[0]/image.jpg"</a>
```

. #element[0] is an element of result list from dataTable and contains values like: 0,1,2,3... etc.
this ends witch error that i could not use #{...} in a template. What should i do? Anybody knows a good solution for this?

Comment: what's the error, and when exactly does it appear.

Comment: The error is on jsp page when i try to type: <a href="myimages/#element[0]/image.jpg"> - i can`t use dynamic element in a tag like #{element}. it has to be something like <a href="index.html"></a>.but i want have dynamic content there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using JSF on JSP, use `<h:outputLink>` and `<h:graphicImage>` instead of `<a>` and `<img>`.

```
<h:outputLink value="myimages/#{element}/image.jpg">
    <h:graphicImage value="myimages/#{element}/image.jpg" />
</h:outputLink>
```

If you're using JSF on Facelets, you can just use EL in template text.

```
<a href="myimages/#{element}/image.jpg">
    <img src="myimages/#{element}/image.jpg" />
</a>
```

Comment: You were right. When i`m using facelets i can use dynamic elements in a tag. Regards for you!